# check two radio buttons of different list in ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic2

[Ionc2 Radio Group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fHlj.png)

As seen in the image I want a two list of radio groups.
But when I try to implement it, Only one option is getting selected of the two list groups.

Please help me to achieve the same.

Comment: Make sure you have 2 different  radio `name`s

Comment: will try the same thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you use 2 different formGroups? If not you should, here is one:

```
 <form (submit)="doSubmit($event)" [formGroup]="langForm">
    <ion-list radio-group formControlName="langs">

      <ion-list-header>
        Language
      </ion-list-header>

      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Go</ion-label>
        <ion-radio value="golang" checked="true"></ion-radio>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Rust</ion-label>
        <ion-radio value="rust"></ion-radio>
      </ion-item>
```

...

Answer (score 0):

Adding name attribute to `<ion-radio>` did the magic

```
                         <ion-list radio-group no-lines >
                              <ion-item>
                                  <ion-label>1</ion-label>
                              <ion-radio name="prithivi">1</ion-radio>
                              </ion-item>
                              <ion-item>
                                  <ion-label>2</ion-label>
                              <ion-radio name="prithivi" >2</ion-radio>
                              </ion-item>
                          </ion-list>

                          <ion-list radio-group no-lines >
                              <ion-item>
                                  <ion-label>3</ion-label>
                              <ion-radio name="abi">3</ion-radio>
                              </ion-item>
                              <ion-item>
                                  <ion-label>4</ion-label>
                              <ion-radio name="abi" >4</ion-radio>
                              </ion-item>
                          </ion-list>
```